# How can I solve the given equation?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

> $$x^{x^{20}}=2^{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}}$$

Can anyone help me understand, how to solve the given equation for $x$?

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be solved by means of elementary functions. Most probably you'll need a "strange" function, like Lambert W function or stuff.

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+4*%7Bx%5E%7Bx%5E%7B20%7D%7D%7D+%3D+2%5E%7Bsqrt%7B2%7D%7D) is what Wolfram|Alpha says. Note: had to edit the input for Wolfram to understand.

Comment: An answer is $$2^{1/8} = \sqrt[8]{2}$$ but I do not recall how to find it. Just remember I have seen this before and that was an answer.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe You could post this as an answer. It is by far the better reply. Can you show that there are no other roots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^{x^{20}}-2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$ If you plot  around $x=1$ it does not look bad at all and shows a root close to $1.1$.

So, use Newton method and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.10000 \\
 1 & 1.09211 \\
 2 & 1.09056 \\
 3 & 1.09051
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the answer from Claude Leibovici the analytical solution is :

$$x^{20}\ln(x)=\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$x^{20}\ln(x^{20})=20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$X=\ln(x^{20})\quad\implies\quad Xe^X=20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$X=W\left(20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$W$ is the LambertW function. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$x^{20}=\exp(X)=\exp\left(W\left(20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
$$x=\exp\left(\frac{1}{20}W\left(20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
Numerically :

$20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}\simeq 9.8025814347$

$X=W(20\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}})\simeq 1.7328679514$

$x=\exp{(X/20)}\simeq 1.0905077327$

This is in good agreement with the result of Claude Leibivici, obtained with Newton method, which of course is more usable on practical viewpoint  ( if the function LambertW isn't implemented in your math. package).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative by [**bisection method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) for $f(x)=x^{x^{20}}-2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$ we have

- $a_1=1 \implies f(a_1)=1-2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}<0$
- $b_1=1.1 \implies f(b_1)=1-2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}>0$

then consider

- $c_1=\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}=1.05 \implies  f(c_1)=(1.05)^{(1.05)^{20}}-2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}>0$

then let $a_2=a_1$ and $b_2=c_1$ and repeat the process taking at each step $a_{i+1}=a_i$ and $b_{i+1}=c_i$ for $c_i>0$ and $a_{i+1}=c_i$ and $b_{i+1}=b_i$ for $c_i<0$.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recall how to find this answer, but the answer (over the reals) is

$$x = 2^{\tfrac{1}{8}} = \sqrt[8]{2}$$

It is clear there is only one answer over the reals because $1^{1^{20}} = 1 < 2^{1/\sqrt{2}}$, $2^{2^{20}}>2^{1/\sqrt{2}}$, and $x^{x^{20}}$ is strictly increasing over the positive reals.